# What percent of deaths caused by influenza list no other comorbidities on the death certificate?

Tags: covid-19, influenza

You may remember the bit of covid misinformation that circulated awhile ago saying that only 6% of the official covid death numbers were actually due to covid https://www.factcheck.org/2020/09/cdc-did-not-admit-only-6-of-recorded-deaths-from-covid-19/ (which is now resurfacing as 3% for Italy https://www.politifact.com/factchecks/2021/nov/10/facebook-posts/italy-didnt-lower-its-covid-19-death-toll-over-97-/).

These claims have been debunked in a number of ways, but they are based on the fact that out of the death certificates that listed covid as a cause of death, only a small percent of them listed covid as the sole cause of death, whereas the rest of them included other causes/comorbidities.

Just for some perspective, I would like to know what percent of death certificates that list regular influenza as a cause of death list it as the *only* cause of death. I suspect the answer is around 3-6%, but trying to find the answer on google just gives me results about the rate for covid.